# Corrupted AVD ini file:C\User\~\.android\avd\avd_name.ini

Tags: android, avd-manager

My System got Shut down (**Blue screen "your pc ran into ..."**) due to unknown(or unfamiliar to me) error of windows 8.1 while While I was working on project on **Android Studio**. So after restart AVD shows this Error shown in Pictures.
And the file on the given location is empty...[**C:\Users\~username~\.android\avd\avdname.ini**]
[Error images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciZog.png)

Answer (score 2):

Step:1

open the file mentioned as corrupted[**C:\Users\~username~\.android\avd\avdname.ini**]
also open folder with same name as that file and open config.ini.

[**C:\Users\~username~\.android\avd\avdname.avd(mine:Pixel_2_xl_API_27.avd)\config.ini**].

Step:2

In avdname.ini file paste the following.[**C:\Users\~username~\.android\avd\avdname.ini**]

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
path=C:\Users\\~userName~\\.android\avd\device_name.avd
path.rel=avd\device_name.avd
target=android-27
```

> target=android-27(api version which you installed mine 27)

all the info above was gathered from config.ini file [**C:\Users\~username~\.android\avd\avdname.avd\config.ini**].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just deleted the corrupted one in AVD Manager (I had nothing to lose) and created another Virtual Device.